# AmCharts 4 - Gantt Chart coloring based on task

Tags: javascript, amcharts, gantt-chart, amcharts4

I want to change the AmCharts Gantt in a way that colorizes the bars(tasks) based on the task-name so that each task with the same name has the same color even if they appear in different categories. I also don't want to have the color defined as a property of the dataset but rather just pull a color from `am4core.ColorSet()` for each task.

In the demo by AmCharts provided below that would mean:

- Gathering requirements = "yellow"
- Producing specifications = "blue"
  and so on.
  Is there a way to achieve this?

Demo I'm working off:
https://www.amcharts.com/demos/gantt-chart-dates/

Comment: I'm working on this too.. but using amcharts5..